# Number 0's and 1's blocks in a binary vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

In MATLAB, there is the `bwlabel` function, that given a binary vector, for instance `x=[1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0]` gives (`bwlabel(x)`):

```
[1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 3 3 3 0]
```

but what I want to obtain is

```
[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 5 6]
```

I know I can negate `x` to obtain (`bwlabel(~x)`)

```
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 3]
```

But how can I combine them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All in one line:

```
y = cumsum([1,abs(diff(x))])
```

Namely, `abs(diff(x))` spots changes in the binary vector, and you gain the output with the cumulative sum.

Answer (score 3):

You can still do it using [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) by [vertically concatenating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) `x` and `~x`, using [4-connected components](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html#bupqqy6-1-n) for the labeling, then taking the [maximum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) down each column:

```
>> max(bwlabel([x; ~x], 4))

ans =

     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     4     4     5     5     5     6
```

However, [the solution from Bentoy13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52875799/52738) is probably a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=[1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0];
A = bwlabel(x);
B = bwlabel(~x);

if x(1)==1
    tmp = A>0;
    A(tmp) = 2*A(tmp)-1;
    tmp = B>0;
    B(tmp) = 2*B(tmp);
    C = A+B
elseif x(1)==0
    tmp = A>0;
    A(tmp) = 2*A(tmp);
    tmp = B>1;
    B(tmp) = 2*B(tmp)-1;
    C = A+B
end
C =

     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     4     4     5     5     5     6
```

You know the first index should remain `1`, but the second index should go from `1` to `2`, the third from `2` to `3` etc; thus even indices should be doubled and odd indices should double minus one. This is given by `A+A-1` for odd entries, and `B+B` for even entries. So a simple check for whether `A` or `B` contains the even points is sufficient, and then simply add the two arrays.

Answer (score -1):

I found this function that does exactly what i wanted:

https://github.com/davidstutz/matlab-multi-label-connected-components

So, clone the repository and compile in matlab using `mex` :

```
mex sp_fast_connected_relabel.cpp
```

Then,

```
labels = sp_fast_connected_relabel(x);
```

Comment: This solution is for 2D, which is a much more difficult problem than in 1D, as you describe here. So yes, it will do the job, but is much more involved (compiling your own mex even) than what is necessary for the one dimensional case you presented in the question.